# Reading file with array in assembly

Tags: linux, file, assembly, x86

I'd like to write function (Linux, assembly, x86), that read and return value (double) from file. I need this to be my initial guess for Newton - Raphson inversion algorithm (I checked this in excel and for random values those values give me correct result in max 8 iterations). My file is something like this:

```
10
0,1
100
0,01
1000
0,001
...
1E+307
1E-307
```

My algorithm should be like this:

```
0. Load value x
1. Check if x > 1 ? (if equal, return 1)
    Yes: jump 2A
    No: jump 2B

2A. i = 0
3A. Check if x <= column(i) ?
    No: i=i+2 jump 3A
    Yes: return column(i+1) jump 4

2B. i = 1
3B. Check if x >= column(i) ?
    No: i=i+2 jump 3B
    Yes: return column(i+1) jump 4

4. End
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
.text
.global read
read:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    fldl    8(%ebp)

    fld1
    fcom    %st(1)
    fstsw   %ax
    sahf
    fstp    %st(0)

ja more 
jb less
je end

more:

less:

end:
leave
ret
```

I have some questions:

1. Is it possible to implement that?
2. Would it be better to use file like this:

   10  0,1

   100 0,01

   1000    0,001

   ...

   1E+307  1E-307
3. Is it good format to read as a double in assembly (for example 1E+75 will be correctly read)?
4. I don't know how to make this works so I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. That's a silly question. Of course it's possible.
2. Doesn't matter whether the separator is a space, a newline or anything else.
3. The easiest way to load the numbers would be a binary format. Of course creating the file would then be harder. There are no instructions that would directly parse such a number for you, you will need to do it yourself. Unless you are forced to implement this all from scratch, you could invoke the C library functions.
4. You need to ask more specific question than that.

Comment: I wrote it (for >1) in C ( http://pastebin.com/YqmE8PBB ) and compiled it witf gcc -S ... and I realized that compilator uses fopen and fscanf from C library, so I will likely do the same.